# Password Problem Can't find a solution that works?

Tags: password

I found my log in password had changed. I have no idea what the new one is. I keep trying to go to grub and get as far as being asked for the new UNIX and there I stick. The keyboard simply does not register the letters I type on the screen.

I have auto login enabled.
I am the administrator.
I cannot type the user name in grub because thanks to a dead y key I have to use the screen keyboard which does not show up in grub.

I am getting desperate as I cannot update etc..

I know what the password was but not what it became
I am having no luck using the terminal either?

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Looks like you need a new keyboard. There is no way around typing the username and password, when resetting a password.

Answer (score 1):

Boot into a live CD/DVD/USB of Ubuntu.

Open up a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>T</kbd> and type in

chnage /dev/sda1 to your partition.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

then type in this command.

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

You can now use the `passwd` command to reset a password.

`sudo passwd <user name>`

that should change your password.

[LiveCdRecovery](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery)